# Can a SQL query compute a loan account statement with interest and principal balances?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, finance

I have a table with a loanee's loan payments. This table has the date the loan was granted, the Amount Granted, Interest Rate on that loan (monthly) and the Dates and Amount paid in each installment.

Loanees do not always pay the same amount, nor do they pay the same day of the month. So the way my company manages interests due, is by calculating the difference in days between payment dates (with the exclusion of the first installment, where the difference in days comes from the date granted and the payment's date). Below, an excerpt from a made up loanee:

| Payment_Number | Date_granted | Amount_Granted | Interest_Rate | Payment_Date | Payment_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-01-11 | 1,100.00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-01-31 | 2,000.00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-03-02 | 800.00 |

My problem is when I calculate the loan account statement. For the first row I know that Accrued Interests is:

```
Amount_Granted * (Interest Rate / 30) * (Payment_Date - Date_Granted)
```

However, I can't do the same for all other installments because, if part of the first one goes to Principal, the new Accrued Interests must be calculated with this new Principal instead of the Amount_Granted like this:

| Payment_Number | Date_granted | Amount_Granted | Interest_Rate | Payment_Date | Payment_Amount | Accrued_interests | Interests_Paid | Principal_Paid | New_Principal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-01-11 | 1,100.00 | 1,000.00 | 1,000.00 | 100.00 | 99,900.00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-01-31 | 2,000.00 | 1,998.00 | 1,998.00 | 2.00 | 99,898.00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 | 100000 | 0.03 | 2021-03-02 | 800.00 | 2,996.94 | 800.00 | 0.00 | 99,898.00 |

In Excel, this is a no-brainer. But I'm struggling to do this in SQL. So far I have tried doing a CASE WHEN, as an example:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN Payment_Number = 1 
           THEN (Amount_Granted * (Interest_Rate / 30) * (Payment_Date - Date_Granted)) 
           ELSE (New_Principal * (Interest_Rate / 30) * (LAG(Payment_Date,1) - Payment_Date)) 
    END AS Accrued_Interests,
    CASE 
        WHEN Accrued_Interests < Payment_Amount 
            THEN Accrued_Interests 
            ELSE Payment_Amount 
    END AS Interests_Paid,
    CASE 
        WHEN Accrued_Interests < Payment_Amount 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE Payment_Amount - Interests_Paid 
    END AS Principal_Paid,
    CASE 
        WHEN Payment_Number = 1 
            THEN Amount_Granted - Principal_Paid 
            ELSE New_Principal - LAG(New_Principal,1) - Principal_Paid 
    END AS New_Principal
FROM 
    MY_TABLE
```

But this yields an error because `New_Principal` has not yet been computed when I'm trying to use it in `Accrued Interests`. In SQLFiddle I get "`Unknown column 'New_Principal' in 'field list'`". I also tried with JOINS but no success, mostly because I have little experience with SQL to know how to do this.

Please, I kindly ask for your orientation. Below, the SQLFiddle Link for a reproduceable example:

[SQLFiddle table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33c6d6c/1/0)

And the SQLFiddle Link for the error:

[SQLFiddle error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/863a89/2)

PS: I know the LAG function is not complete, I just wanted to simplify things. Also: accrued interests that are not paid in complete go to an interests balance, but for the sake of simplification I am ignoring them.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in SQL using a recursive CTE. A typical query won't do since you need to process the rows in sequence and every next row depends on the current one, and so on.

Comment: Consider that just because you *can* do something using a particular technology (in this case SQL), doesn't mean it's a good idea, and it could even be a very bad idea. In this case, using the database to *store* and *retrieve* the data, the using application code to *process* it, would likely be simpler. Trying to use SQL to write app code is generally a poor tech choice.

Comment: @Bohemian actually has a point, however, I decided on using SQL because it is better than the alternative of using Excel and having to rely on this one file every time I need to access the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in your example are a bit off and don't really follow the formula you specified. I tweaked the numbers to demonstrate how SQL Server can perform the calculations according to your algorithm.

You can use a Recursive CTE to compute each payment according to the dates and updated principal from the previous payment, as in:

```
with
p as (
  select *,
    payment_amount - interest_paid as principal_paid,
    amount_granted - (payment_amount - interest_paid) as new_principal, cast(null as float) as prev_principal
  from (
    select *,
      case when payment_amount < accrued_interest then payment_amount else accrued_interest end as interest_paid
    from (
      select
        Payment_Number, Date_granted, Amount_Granted,
        Interest_Rate, Payment_Date, Payment_Amount,
        Amount_Granted * (Interest_Rate / 30) * datediff(day, date_granted, payment_date) as accrued_interest
      from account where payment_number = 1
    ) x
  ) y
 union all
  select
    Payment_Number, Date_granted, Amount_Granted,
    Interest_Rate, Payment_Date, Payment_Amount,
    accrued_interest, interest_paid,
    payment_amount - interest_paid,
    prev_principal - (payment_amount - interest_paid),
    prev_principal
  from (
    select *,
      case when payment_amount < accrued_interest then payment_amount else accrued_interest end as interest_paid
    from (
      select a.Payment_Number, a.Date_granted, a.Amount_Granted,
        a.Interest_Rate, a.Payment_Date, a.Payment_Amount,
        p.new_principal * (a.Interest_Rate / 30) * datediff(day, a.date_granted, a.payment_date) as accrued_interest,
        p.new_principal as prev_principal
      from p
      join account a on a.payment_number = p.payment_number + 1
    ) z
  ) w
)
select * from p;
```

Result:

```
Payment_Number  Date_granted  Amount_Granted  Interest_Rate  Payment_Date  Payment_Amount  accrued_interest  interest_paid  principal_paid  new_principal  prev_principal
--------------  ------------  --------------  -------------  ------------  --------------  ----------------  -------------  --------------  -------------  --------------
             1   2021-01-01          100,000           0.03   2021-01-11            1,100             1,000          1,000             100         99,900          <null>
             2   2021-01-01          100,000           0.03   2021-01-31            3,000             2,997          2,997               3         99,897          99,900
             3   2021-01-01          100,000           0.03   2021-03-02            2,800          5,993.82          2,800               0         99,897          99,897
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fcdde99dfd5eef3e4c8ee8afc98ee8a5).

Comment: You are amazing. After some tests you have it right. I see the method works, but something I didn't explicitly mentioned is that `Accrued_Interests` for the second installment and onwards are calculated with the difference in days between the current installment and the last one. I managed to tweak the code a bit and inserted `p.new_principal * (a.Interest_Rate / 30) * datediff(day, LAG(a.payment_date, 1, p.payment_date) over (Partition by a.payment_number order by a.payment_number), a.payment_date) as accrued_interest` in Ln31 and now it works like a charm.

Comment: I do have some questions as to how does this work though (see, I'm not very knowledgeable with CTEs and can't understand what do they do). What I understand is that it creates table p as a UNION of table "Account" with calculations of installments with payment number equal to 1 and another table for calculations of installments with payment number not equal to 1. But how is this working when you are using table p in Ln33? You are arriving to my same predicament of self referencing a table but have no problem.

Comment: Essentially a recursive CTE has an "anchor query" and a "recursive/iterative query" separated by `UNION ALL`. The anchor query is executed only once (typically to select the starting point). The recursive query joins the new rows (row #1) just produced with the main table to produce more new rows (row #2); then, each new row produced becomes the input for the next iteration of the recursive query, It finally stops when the recursive query does not produce any more rows.

Comment: I think I get your point? It gets me thinking though, what would happen when I deploy it with the real database (I have no way of trying it now). We have multiple customers and multiple loans. Each loan has its own ID, so I would believe that using a PARTITION BY in Ln16 will suffice?

Comment: I would test it thoroughly, at least with a few comprehensive test scenarios. Better be safe than sorry.